# How to split the data i recover from my webservice?

Tags: ajax, json

Hi can anyone help me with this issue?

```
var sendRequest = function(){

 $.ajax({     
 type: 'POST',    
 accept: 'application/json',
 url: 'http://easybusservices.cloudapp.net/EasWebService/EasWS.asmx/JSONReturn?',     
 contentType: 'application/json', 
 dataType:"json/text",
 data: JSON.stringify({ test: 'heahhaeh' }),
 success: function (data, status) {alert("success" + data);},     
 error: function(data, status){ alert("error" + data);
 }
```

The value that i get from data is  "success{"Test":"heahhaeh"}{"d":null}"
now i need to break it down and just save Test:heahhaeh only.

i am developing a samsung smart tv app fyi.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-domain XHR requests won't work. Only JSONP.